# How to save the data of an array by prompts and bond with a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, prompt, console.log

The data that is saved in an array through prompts as I do to link it with a class and display it with a method (console.log (information ())

```
class Libro {

   constructor(titulo, autor, año, genero) {

      this.titulo = titulo
      this.Autor = autor
      this.Año = año
      this.Genero = genero
   }

   informacion() {
      return console.log(`El libro ${this.titulo} del autor ${this.Autor} fue publicado en el año ${this.Año} y es de genero ${this.Genero}`);
   }
}

let titulo1 = prompt('Introduce el titulo del libro')
let autor1 = prompt('Introduce el autor del libro')
let año1 = prompt('Introduce el año en que fue publicado el libro')
let genero1 = prompt('Introduce el genero literario del libro')

let libro1 = [titulo1, autor1, año1, genero1];

libro1.push(new Libro(titulo, autor, año, genero))

console.log(libro1.informacion());
```

Comment: I want to do this but with prompts and I don't know how to do it .  

Example:

`const book1 = new Libro('LordRings', 'Tolkien', 1954, 'Adventure')

console.log(book1.informacion()); 

"El libro LordRings del autor Tolkien fue publicado en el año 1954 y es de genero Adventure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class identifiers refer to the class constructor function.

Replace

```
let libro1 = [titulo1, autor1, año1, genero1];

libro1.push(new Libro(titulo, autor, año, genero))

console.log(libro1.Libro());
```

with

```
let libro1 = new Libro(titulo, autor, año, genero)
libro1.informacion()   // call the informacion method of libro1
```

which creates a class instance object, assigns it to `libro1`, and then calls the `informacion` method of `libro1`.

If you want an array of book objects, you could save `libro1` (and other books) in an array:

```
const libri = [];
...  // create libro1
libri.push(libro1);
...  // create libro2
libri.push( libro2);
```

To create more than one book, try putting the prompts inside a function that returns a `Libro` class object. That way all books use the same set of prompts.

---

In response to comment, the `informacion` method already calls `console.log` and returns `undefined` if that is what `console.log` returns. Returning an information string may better suit your purpose:

```
informacion() {
      return `El libro ${this.titulo} del autor ${this.Autor} fue publicado en el año ${this.Año} y es de genero ${this.Genero}`;
   }
```

---

If the result of the prompts is saved in an array, like

```
let arr = [titulo, Autor, Año, Genaro];
```

you can pass them to the constuctor function using [`rest parameter syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
let libro = new Libro( ...arr );
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, because the information that is saved in the prompts, simply remains in the let variables, but they are not sent anywhere to make push with the class.

Comment: You do not "push the class" -  `Libro` is a constructor function, not an array.  `titulo`, `Autor`,  `Año` and `Genero` values are saved as properties of `Libro` class objects, not as entries in an array. Please reseach how JavaScript implements the `class` keyword.

Comment: Yes, my friend, I know that it is not an array, maybe I did not understand well, but that is my question, how do I store the data of an array in the constructor parameters, if they were entered by prompts? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Now I understand part of my problem, I am confusing arrays with objects, better forget my question I will leave this exercise for later when I have more knowledge, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: I didn't understand from the question that you wanted to start with an array of parameter values. The updated answer describes the "rest parameter syntax" that can be used with JavaScript class names..

Comment: Finally I was able to solve it, what happens is that your code as you say from the beginning was always fine, but you had not noticed that my prompt variables had a 1 at the end, but that was the answer friend lol thank you very much. Now how do I close this question or do I value you here? I am new here.

Comment: If my answer provided the solution (e.g. if you used rhe rest parameter syntax ) then accepting the answer is appropriate. Using comments to clear up misunderstandings is quite normal.